# facebook keep me logged in vs not keeping me logged in

Tags: php, facebook, session, cookies, authentication

I have built login systems in php and I always use session to login the user. As a results of using session, my browser always creates a cookie called PHPSESSID. And if the user checks the **remember me** option, I will set username and password into cookies. Please note that these cookies are accessible in the browser.

Since, I always like to see how others do their login system, I decided to test this fact with facebook. I logged into my facebook, without checking the **Keep me logged in** and then I check the cookies but I didn't see PHPSESSID cookie. Does anyone know why?

For the second time, I logged into facebook, this time I checked the **keep me logged in**. Then I checked the cookies and I saw the same cookies with same expiry date as in my **first** try.

if the *first* and *second* try results in same cookies, then what is the difference? Or better say what is the point of using it?

Comment: For questions about facebook internals, you have to ask facebook, not here.

Comment: I think the reason for that is because they can't store so many sessions on the server, therefore they have to rely on cookies...

Comment: @SokhratSikar Facebook has plenty of capacity to store sessions. They likely use something like a memcached cluster to do so.

Comment: I am actually speculating facebook and that's because they have one of the largest databases in the world. If you don't know the answer, why do you jump in. And if I had a clue, then I wouldn't ask question?

Comment: wouldn't storing your sessions in several hundreds of memcached cluster's, slow your service? I think it's better to use cookies than session. My solution for cookie security is to generate a random 50 char, adding salt and then hashing sha512 and storing the token in database.

Comment: Christ, no. It wouldn't slow things down. Facebook is fairly open about what technology drives their services, and [memcached is a major component](https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=39391378919). They were handling 200k memcached requests per second **in 2008**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And if the user checks the remember me option, I will set username and password into cookies.

Please, don't do that. Passwords and other sensitive data shouldn't be saved into cookies.

> Since, I always like to see how others do their login system, I decided to test this fact with facebook. I logged into my facebook, without checking the Keep me logged in and then I check the cookies but I didn't see PHPSESSID cookie. Does anyone know why?

A session cookie doesn't have to be named `PHPSESSID`. I show 11 cookies from Facebook, several of which have data that might be session information.

> if the first and second try results in same cookies, then what is the difference? Or better say what is the point of using it?

The remember-me functionality could easily be server-side.

There's more than one way of doing pretty much everything in web development. Facebook's a complex system, and as such they're sometimes going to use more complex solutions than is necessary on your smaller projects.

Comment: as long you hash the password, you should be fine storing it in the cookie

Comment: The remember-me functionality could easily be server-side. Session expires when you close the browser, where as setting cookies don't expire even when you close the browser, therefore I don't think you can implement remember-me functionality on the server side.

Comment: Sure you can. You make the cookies last forever, but you decide on the server-side whether or not to request the user's password anyways. If they haven't had any activity after x hours and they didn't check "remember me", you present them with a login box despite the valid cookie.